# cogroup like operation for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I was trying to using pandas to analysis a fairly large data set (~5GB). I wanted to divide the data sets into groups, then perform a Cartesian product on each group, and then aggregate the result.

The `apply` operation of pandas is quite expressive, I could first `group`, and then do the Cartesian product on each group using `apply`, and then aggregate the result using `sum`. The problem with this approach, however, is that `apply` is not lazy, it will compute all the intermediate results before the aggregation, and the intermediate results (Cartesian production on each group) is very large.

I was looking at Apache Spark and found one very interesting operator called `cogroup`. The definition is here:

> When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, Iterable, Iterable) tuples. This operation is also called groupWith.

This seems to be exactly what I want. If I could first `cogroup` and then do a `sum`, then the intermediate results won't be expanded (assuming `cogroup` works in the same lazy fashion as `group`).

Is there operation similar to `cogroup` in pandas, or how to achieve my goal efficiently?

Here is my example:

I want to group the data by `id`, and then do a Cartesian product for each group, and then group by `cluster_x` and `cluster_y` and aggregate the `count_x` and `count_y` using `sum`. The following code works, but is extremely slow and consumes too much memory.

```
# add dummy_key to do Cartesian product by merge
df['dummy_key'] = 1

def join_group(g):
    return pandas.merge(g, g, on='dummy_key')\
    [['cache_cluster_x', 'count_x', 'cache_cluster_y', 'count_y']]

df_count_stats = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=True).apply(join_group).\
    groupby(['cache_cluster_x', 'cache_cluster_y'], as_index=False)\
    [['count_x', 'count_y']].sum()
```

A toy data set

```
   id cluster  count
0  i1       A      2
1  i1       B      3
2  i2       A      1
3  i2       B      4
```

Intermediate result after the `apply` (can be large)

```
     cluster_x  count_x cluster_y  count_y
id                                        
i1 0         A        2         A        2
   1         A        2         B        3
   2         B        3         A        2
   3         B        3         B        3
i2 0         A        1         A        1
   1         A        1         B        4
   2         B        4         A        1
   3         B        4         B        4
```

The desired final result

```
  cluster_x cluster_y  count_x  count_y
0         A         A        3        3
1         A         B        3        7
2         B         A        7        3
3         B         B        7        7
```

Comment: Could you give a small self-contained example with fake data to show what you want?  (E.g. I don't see why you can't move a summation into the apply to avoid expanding more than one group at a time, but maybe that doesn't work in a real case for some reason.)

Comment: @DSM I have attached an example. The summation in one group won't reduce the size of the result, the summation I want to do is across different groups. I actually did another `groupby`.

Comment: Is that the right frame under "toy data set"? It doesn't have an id column, and looks just like your final result.

Comment: My bad. Just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt failed, sort of: while I was able to limit the memory use (by summing over the Cartesian product within each group), it was considerably slower than the original.  But for your particular desired output, I think we can simplify the problem considerably:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def fake_data(nids, nclusters, ntile):
    ids = ["i{}".format(i) for i in range(1,nids+1)]
    clusters = ["A{}".format(i) for i in range(nclusters)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ids, clusters], names=["id", "cluster"]))
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = pd.concat([df]*ntile)
    df["count"] = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=len(df))
    return df


def join_group(g):
    m= pd.merge(g, g, on='dummy_key')
    return m[['cluster_x', 'count_x', 'cluster_y', 'count_y']]

def old_method(df):
    df["dummy_key"] = 1
    h1 = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=True).apply(join_group)
    h2 = h1.groupby(['cluster_x', 'cluster_y'], as_index=False)
    h3 = h2[['count_x', 'count_y']].sum()
    return h3

def new_method1(df):
    m1 = df.groupby("cluster", as_index=False)["count"].sum()
    m1["dummy_key"] = 1
    m2 = m1.merge(m1, on="dummy_key")
    m2 = m2.sort_index(axis=1).drop(["dummy_key"], axis=1)
    return m2
```

which gives (with `df` as your toy frame):

```
>>> new_method1(df)
  cluster_x cluster_y  count_x  count_y
0         A         A        3        3
1         A         B        3        7
2         B         A        7        3
3         B         B        7        7
>>> df2 = fake_data(100, 100, 1)
>>> %timeit old_method(df2)
1 loops, best of 3: 954 ms per loop
>>> %timeit new_method1(df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.58 ms per loop
>>> (old_method(df2) == new_method1(df2)).all().all()
True
```

and even

```
>>> df2 = fake_data(100, 100, 100)
>>> %timeit new_method1(df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 88.8 ms per loop
```

Whether this will be enough of an improvement to handle your actual case, I'm not sure.

Comment: You are right. For this particular problem I could have simplified using `new_method1`. Generally though I don't know if `pandas` can handle two `groupby` or more complicated operations lazily (without expanding all the intermediate results. I am looking at Apache-Spark and it seems to solve the issue. But I hope `pandas`  can also support arbitrary lazy expressions (currently it only supports one groupby and aggregate, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Still after 7 years the cogroup operator is missing from pandas.